# Applescript Passing a Variable Into Shell Command

Tags: applescript

I am attempting to make a script to mount a drive. As this is something I do frequently. However, I am not familiar with Applescript. Thus far I have not been able to find how to pass a query into a command?

If you wouldn't mind showing me that would be awesome! A little explanation would also be great as I do want to understand what it does.

```
(choose from list {"disk0s2", "disk2s1", "disk2s2", "disk3s1", "disk3s2", "disk4s1", "disk4s2"} with prompt "What disk are you trying to mount?")
set disk to result as text

repeat 5 times
do shell script "diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk3s1" with administrator privileges
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must replace part of the do shell script command with your variable and concat all with & :

```
 do shell script "diskutil mount readOnly /dev/" & disk" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: I had to take out the quotes after the word disk, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Applescript? This is trivial with bash. If you make a script for each disk, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk2s1
```

You can make the script double-clickable by right-clicking, **Open With**, then **Other...** and selecting **Terminal**. (You may need to select **All Applications** when browsing for the Terminal application).

Comment: I had thought about that, but this makes it one script instead of having multiple files.